# <SF Symbol name> not found in table SymbolNameOverrides

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sf-symbols, xcode12.5

After reopening an older project in Xcode 12.5 and updating the project settings, to get rid of the warning telling me to do so (it only updated some localization settings), I see a lot of error messages logged in the Xcode console saying `[SF Symbol name] not found in table SymbolNameOverrides of bundle CFBundle 0x10304ae20 </System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilitySharedSupport.framework`, for almost all usages of SF Symbol names in the code.

**Example:**
`2021-05-21 15:44:43.264274+0200 MyAppName[17837:4945987] [strings] ERROR: tray.and.arrow.up.fill not found in table SymbolNamesAutoGenerated of bundle CFBundle 0x1029385d0 </System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilitySharedSupport.framework> (not loaded)`

Has anyone encountered the same issue and maybe found a solution?

**Note:** I do not remember receiving this error in prior versions of Xcode 12.4.

**Edit:** The SF Symbols seem to be displayed correctly, despite the error messages.

Comment: What are SymbolNameOverrides and SymbolNamesAutoGenerated? Your own code or?

Comment: Nope, I have nothing like that in my code. Searched in the entire project for the 'SymbolNameOverrides' and 'SymbolNamesAutoGenerated' and got 0 results. I'm also not using any no third-party frameworks

Comment: I do have the same issue. I localised and added accessibility to an iOS13 swiftUI 1 app and I got these warnings. I do not know yet why.

Comment: I have the same problem: "Show non-localized strings" used to be a wonderful tool to see if I missed a translation. But not it's flooded with the symbol-names.
That doesn't affect the build/end result, but it makes the process a but unpleasant.

Answer (score 6):

#### This fixed it for me

When localising the app do not forget to uncheck the `Show non-localised strings` when finished.
[image: screenshot of scheme in Xcode]
Otherwise you might end up with more warning like the one below:

[image: screenshot from console]